# MapActivity ClassDefNotFoundException at runtime

Tags: java, android, google-maps, noclassdeffounderror, mapactivity

My Activity extends from MapActivity, I have descried it correctly in the manifest, I have put the `<uses-library>` tag inside the `<application>` tag I am building with goole apis library and the maps.jar is there only one time(no duplicates) and the app runs and works perfect on most devices.
However I got a crash report with ClassDefNotFoundException which occurred on ZTE Blade device with Android 2.1. I am building with google apis 2.1
Does anyone have suggestions for that?

I am providing the stack trace too:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2165)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2160)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.testing.asd.android.ui.InfoActivity
at com.testing.asd.android.ui.HomeScreen.onClick(HomeScreen.java:60)
... 14 more
```

com.testing.asd.android.ui.InfoActivity extends MapActivity. The problem is only on one device so far. I tested it on Android 2.3 and 4.2 and it is ok there.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the missing class. Can you include the stacktrace too?

Comment: I usually get NoClassDefFoundError when I try to use a class that has additional 3rd Party dependencies which are not currently on the classpath. Instead of a ClassNotFoundException, when the actual class isn't available. Are you sure that all 3rd Party dependencies are available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the case with the ZTE Blade, but there are some devices (such as the Kindle Fire) that don't have the Google APIs. I think these phones will show a NoClassDefFoundError if your app uses MapView.

Comment: I tend to agree with you but isn't there a way to fix this by exporting the apis library during the build?